# How to choose the optimal parameter for SVM regression?

Tags: svm

I know that`tune()` in package `e1071` is useful to choose the optimal parameters for the SVM regression.But I just don't know how to to select the suitable ranges for parameters like `gamma`,`cost` and `epsilon`?

```
x<-tune.svm(rg~.,data=train,kernel="radial",
            gamma = c(0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1.3,10,30),cost=2^(2:9),epsilon =c(0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1.3,10,30) )
```

The parameters above is just chosen randomly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Many thanks!!

ok. Here is my result with the train data after `tune.svm`,with the x axis being the fitted data and y axis being the actual data. Is there any idea on how to improve the SVM performance?[image]

and the data in train set:
`> head(train)
           rg weather sex member_type annual_income Weekend age_group
1 0.035725277       6   2           3             1       2         3
2 1.693898548       6   2           1             5       2         1
3 0.009012839       1   2           3             1       1         3
4 0.014902879       6   2           3             2       2         3
6 0.003531616       6   2           3             1       1         2
7 0.001575542       6   1           3             2       1         3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use exactly what you are using, which is a range that grows times 3. In some situations I have tried multiples of 1.5, that would be (0.01, 0.015, 0.03...). I improved my performance a little but not too much. It all depends on how long your training lasts.

I would try as minimum a smaller number like 0.0001 and as maximum 1000. Maybe 1000 is to much but I always try an order of magnitude bigger than what I think it's my maximum, that I would say it's 100.

Comment: I have just add the result after `tune.svm`, but the result does not seem good. can you help me with that?

Comment: I would try to implement the optimization myself, instead of using the automatic range c(0.01,0.03...), I would do a for loop. For each value in the parameters, train the svm and test it to get the performance. Then you keep the values with the highest performance